# Selecting the other item in a 2-item list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have a list with two items. I would like to iterate over this list to avoid duplicating very similar code:

```
for item in ["str1", "str2"]
    if <condition>:
        var1 = item
    else:
        var1 = <the "other" item in the list>
    
    #other code that depends on var1 and on item
```

In the first iteration, if we end up in the else branch, var1 should be assigned the value "str2", while in the second iteration, var1 would be assigned "str1".

The only way I can think of solving this is without a loop, i.e, repeating my code. Is there a way I can keep the loop?

EDIT1: Added the fact that the code within the loop has statements that use both var1 and item.

EDIT2: Here's a less psuedo-code like example of what I'm trying to do:

```
myList = ["str1", "str2"]
outList = []
isSame = True # or False
for item in myList:
    val1 = item if isSame else #the other item
    str3 = "some text {0} some more text {1}".format(item, val1)
    outList.append(str3)
```

Without a loop, this would look like:

```
item = "str1"
val1 = "str1" if isSame else "str2"
str3 = "some text {0} some more text {1}".format(item, val1)
outList.append(str3)

item = "str2"
str3 = "some text {0} some more text {1}".format(item, val1)
outList.append(str3)
```

Comment: Why do you have a loop? Just do `if <condition> var1 = mylist[0]; else: var1 = mylist[1]`.

Comment: This for loop is unnecessary as @PranavHosangadi said, but if you still want to use for-loop then add a break after if condition

Comment: Pranav and ozcanyarimdunya, thank you for your comments. I realized my question was incomplete. The "rest" of my code (which is the last comment) uses both var1 and each item of the list.

Comment: You could use a counter variable `i`and then read the array (say it is called `a`) with `a[i]`and `a[-i]`

Comment: Can there be more than two elements in your list?

Comment: No it's just two. I thought of making a class that acts like a boolean with "str1" and "str2" as "literals" and then use a not operator but that would be overkill for something so small :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the edits, it sounds like this is more about the algorithm rather than about Python-specific syntax.

Here's my take, works with two items but could probably be extended to more:

```py
isSame = True
items = ["str1", "str2"]
len_items = len(items)

for item in items:
    var1 = item 

    if not isSame:
        # Get index of the "next" item or 0 if item is the last:
        next_index = (items.index(item) + 1) % len_items
        var1 = items[next_index]

    # other code that depends on var1 and on item

    print(item, var1)
```

Gives:

```
str1 str1
str2 str2
```

if `isSame` is `True`, and:

```
str1 str2
str2 str1
```

if `isSame` is `False`.

Comment: This works if the list.append() was the only statement. My apologies, I should have been more generic. It would have been better for me to say val2 = #expr that depends on item, outList.append((val1, val2))

Comment: Thank you! This helped. :) I also came up with a solution of my own. But I'm marking yours as the answer since it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your looking for a [ternary operator](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html).

Here is an example of the syntax :

```
is_nice = True
state = "nice" if is_nice else "not nice"
```

In your case, with a list :

```
my_list = ["str1", "str2"]
var1 = my_list[0] if <condition> else my_list[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems clunky, but

```
myList = ["str1", "str2"]
for item in myList:
    if <condition>:
        var1 = item
    else:
        var1 = [i for i in myList if i != item][0]
    
    #other code that depends on var1 and on item
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `enumerate()` function to iterate over the list *and* the indices of the elements simultaneously. Then, check your condition and replace the item with the element of `mylist` at `newindex`. How do you get `newindex`? By adding one to `index`, and then taking the remainder against the length of the list. This means if your condition isn't satisfied, `newindex` will be the next element of the list. If this is the last element of the list, it will wrap around to the first.

In the case of `len(mylist) = 2`, doing this gives us the *other* element of the list.
In this example, the condition is that the last character of `item` must be `"1"`.

```
def is_same(x):
    return x[-1] == "1"

mylist = ["str1", "str2"]
newlist = []

for index, item in enumerate(mylist):
    if is_same(item):
        var1 = item
    else:
        newindex = (index + 1) % len(mylist)
        var1 = mylist[newindex]

    # Do other shenanigans with item
    value = item + " hello " + var1
    newlist.append(value)
```

After running this code, `newlist` contains two items, -- the first one derived from only `str1`, but the second one coming from both `str1` and `str2`

```
# newlist: 
['str1 hello str1', 'str2 hello str1']
```

Answer (score 0):

If creating the outList is your only task to be done in the for loop then you could avoid the for loop by doing something like below:

```
myList = ["str1", "str2"]
outList = []
isSame = True # or False
outList = list(zip(myList, reversed(myList)) if isSame else zip(myList, myList))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking p3j4p5 reply as the answer since it looks cleaner. All this while, I was thinking in terms of booleans since ideally what I need is a way of assigning the "not" of the element in the list. I figured out a way to write the code while thinking in this way. Posting this here for critique. Is this is a bad way to code this?

```
myList = {True: "str1", False: "str2"}
outList = []
isSame = True # or False
for key in myList:
    item  = myList[key]
    val1 = myList[key] if isSame else myList[not key]
    str3 = "some text {0} some more text {1}".format(item, val1)
    outList.append(str3)
```

The reason I'm thinking in terms of booleans is because the strings "str1" and "str2" mean opposite things in my actual code. I assumed that writing the code in terms of booleans would make the code readable in terms of conveying what I'm trying to do.

Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could convert them to sets and subtract.

```py
items = ["str1", "str2"]
for item in items:
    if <condition>:
        var1 = item
    else:
        var1 = list(set(items) - {item})[0]
```